# How to select particular key from json map in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have json document in ES like this:

```json
{
  "indicators": 
    {
      "i1": { ... }
    }, 
    {
      "i2": { ... }
    }
}
```

The `indicators` is a map from string key to object. I need to select document which contains particular key.

Trying to query it like this from Kibana UI:

> indicators.i2 :*

But this doesn't work. What is the correct query in such case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you need to get those documents that contain a particular field (in your case suppose the field is `indicators.i1`)

To achieve the required results, you need to use [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html).

Adding a working example with index data and search query

**Index Data:**

```
POST tidx/_doc/1
{
  "indicators": [
    {
      "i1": {
        "city": "indore"
      }
    },
    {
      "i2": {
        "city": "bangalore"
      }
    }
  ]
}

POST tidx/_doc/2
{
  "indicators": [
    {
      "i2": {
        "city": "bangalore"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
POST tidx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "indicators.i1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Response:**

```
"hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "tidx",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "indicators" : [
            {
              "i1" : {
                "city" : "indore"
              }
            },
            {
              "i2" : {
                "city" : "bangalore"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```